# Picking integer numbers over discret intervals with c++

Tags: c++, random, integer, set, intervals

Given a set of N integers numbers (all having 1 unit distance from each other) I would like to create a vector using each of those numbers T times each.

Let's say X= [1,2,...,N] is my set of numbers and I want to create a vector of T.N size such that each x in X appears $T$ times each (the order does not matter).

My idea is the following:

Using an original library of c++ I pick a random number from X and save the number of times this number was the pick, after some x be chosen T times I break the set X into two parts, say X1=[1,2,...,x) and X2=(x,...,N]. Therefore, in order to randomly take the next number, I generate a uniform (0,1) number before, if it is bigger than 1/2 I pick the new number over X2 and from X1 otherwise.

Keeping on like this, let's say there are now K numbers that were pick T times already. I will pick the next number from one of the K+1 sets generated by removing these selected values. In order to pick some of these intervals, I again generate a (0,1) number and ''break'' the (0,1) interval over K+1 equal parts of length (1/K+1) and pick the next set accordingly.

Does that make sense?

Comment: are you asking how one would implement this in C++?

Comment: Just append X T times to itself. And shuffle the result if you need a random distribution.

Comment: If generating this vector is a step towards sampling from a discrete distribution, then a [`std::discrete_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution) will achieve the sampling you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

How about copy the list into a vector three times then randomize? `<algorithm>` has `std::random_shuffle()` and `std::shuffle()`.